# does a partial view always need a model passed from the top-level view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Here's a url describing partial views in MVC:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial

Based on this url it looks like partial views are bound to a model that's passed to it from the partial view's top-level/parent view.  Is this the standard and expected way to implement partial views?

This seems to indicate that a partial view intended to be used from several different parent views should have some type of associated specialized class that can be used to return its data to multiple different viewmodel builders. Is this the correct interpretation of the MVC partial view architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By default it uses the parent views (view) model. But you can always pass another model to it explicitly ( as long as the type of the model passing is the same type which the view is strongly typed to).

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView",Model)
```

Or

```
 @{ var data = new MyClass { SomeProperty = "SomeValue"};
 @Html.Partial("MyPartialView",data )
```

Assuming `MyPartialView` is strongly typed to `MyClass`

`@model MyClass`

For example, If your main view is strongly typed to `Order` class which has a `Customer` property like this

```
public class Order
{
  public int OrderId { set;get;}
  public Customer Customer { set;get;}
}
public class Customer
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

You can call the partial view which is strongly typed to the Customer class from your main view by passing the `Model.Customer`

```
@model Order
<h2>@Model.OrderId</h2>
@Html.Partial("Customer",Model.Customer)
```

Assuming your Customer view is strongly typed to `Customer` type

```
@model Customer
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

You can call the Customer partial view from anywhere as long as you have a Customer object to pass to it. ( IF your parent view is strongly typed to Customer class, you do not need to explicitly pass it)

Comment: thanks shyju. so it sounds like the model can not be associated with the partial view independently.  i.e. - the model for the partial view must always be passed from the parent view right?

Comment: No !It can have another type. See the answer

Comment: thanks shyju so it sounds like I could call @Html.Partial("CustomerDetails") with no model param and MVC would automatically try to bind to the parent model by default?  In the example you provided above, that would be a Customer model?

Comment: Yes. If you are using the overload which takes only the view name, It takes the parent model.